# Command run with shell but get stuck with QProcess

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qprocess

I'm trying to execute some command with QProcess. Executing from terminal works fine.

For example, I want to execute following command: `fpscan /path --report --verbose=2 --nospin` (scanning files with f-prot antivirus).
I'm trying the following code:

```
QProcess* p = new QProcess(this);
p->start("fpscan", params);
```

process get stuck.

From `ps -Al | grep fpscan` output I see, that this process opens another process.

```
process     |    WCHAN    |    TIME
1           |    wait     |  00:00:00
2           |    pipe_w   |  00:00:00
```

strace command:

1. wait4(-1,
2. read(0,

Any suggestions?

P.S.: another command `clamscan /path params` works fine with QProcess.

**Update:** I've tried to use fork, execl, and it works, so the problem is with QT and QProcess.

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
    execl("/usr/local/bin/fpscan", "fpscan", "/path", ... , NULL);
}
```

Comment: Both with same `/path`? Because there could be some bad symbol.

Comment: It's not a problem, I've tried with /tmp.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the process is trying to read from stdin.

Comment: What happens is that when you use plain fork+exec the process uses the parents stdin/stdout but QProcess will create its own pipe.